# What to respond if someone knocks on the door when you are using the changing room?

Tags: phrase-request, american-english

When I am in the changing room, sometimes others knock on the door to check whether the room is empty. As a non-native English speaker, I am curious what do you respond in this case?

I tried to say "I am here!" or "yes?", but I think it is kind of strange. So what do you usually say?

Comment: Sorry, Mate! There's no toilet paper in this one either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say "occupied".

It probably doesn't matter too much what you say, as long as you don't indicate that you want a response.  So, I think "Yes?" is inappropriate, but "I am here" is probably okay (if somewhat unusual).

Comment: One might also try something like, "I'll be out in a moment." That allows the person knocking to realize the room is occupied, but maybe seems a little more polite. There's no getting around it, though, there's going to be a little bit of awkwardness no matter what get said.

Comment: @J.R.: Curiously, although obviously I'm a native speaker, I might sometimes shout something like ["**Occupado!**"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ocupado) in such a situation. If only to distance myself from that "awkwardness" by briefly affecting a different persona.

Comment: Not that it's wrong, but "occupied" sounds a bit stiff to me.  I prefer to say "Just a minute please."

Comment: Depends on who comes a-knocking ;)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ocupado has one "c" in Spanish